# Gradient of vector norm and minimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider error function $E(\mathbf w)$ as follow:

[image]

Setting above equations' gradient w.r.t zero, and solving for $\mathbf w$ we obtain following equation. I am unable to understand how did we get following equation and why there is identity matrix $\mathbf I$ and why is it inside the inverse term?

[image]

Comment: It helps to know that the gradient of $f(x) = \frac12 \|Ax + b\|^2$ is $\nabla f(x) = A^T(Ax + b)$.  Note that $w^T w = \| w \|^2$ and that you can write the first term in the objective as $\frac12 \| \Phi w - t \|^2$ for appropriate choices of $\Phi$ and $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error function is a typical "sum over vector components (squared)", which can be better expressed in terms of the [Frobenius (:) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).  So re-writing the function and taking its differential yields
$$\eqalign{
 E &= \frac{1}{2}\Big[(\Phi w-t):(\Phi w-t) + \lambda w:w\Big] \cr\cr
dE &= (\Phi w-t):(\Phi dw) + \lambda w:dw \cr
   &= \Big[\Phi^T(\Phi w-t) + \lambda w\Big]:dw \cr\cr
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w} &= \Phi^T\Phi w - \Phi^T t + \lambda w \cr
}$$
Now set the gradient to zero and rearrange to obtain
$$\eqalign{
0 &= \Phi^T\Phi w - \Phi^T t + \lambda w \cr
0 &= (\Phi^T\Phi + \lambda I) w - \Phi^T t \cr
(\Phi^T\Phi + \lambda I) w &= \Phi^T t \cr
w &= (\Phi^T\Phi + \lambda I)^{-1}\Phi^T t \cr
}$$

If you're uncomfortable with Frobenius products, you can replace them via the Frobenius-Trace equivalence $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$